# ALTBeacon library threads impacting other thread functions in application

Tags: multithreading, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

We are writing an client server application which communicates with the server to inform its BLE location and get updates from the server to perform any requested action. This application uses the ALT beacon Library to detect the BLE proximity and shows the proximity range to device user on the UI. The application has service and activity and both of these will multiple async tasks communicate with server very frequently (~every 30 second) when the BLE is running. We have realized that when the BLE proximity enabled (starts ranging and monitoring), the async tasks threads getting executed very late and this is leading to delay in communicating to server. I would like to understand is there any concern with the way I am using the ALT beacon library which will create more threads or leaks?

The pseudo code is below:

```
public class BeaconScanner extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, ServerCallBack, BeaconConsumer {
    protected static final String TAG = "BeaconScanner";
    private static BeaconManager beaconManager;

    private static Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            refreshInfo();
            timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 30 * 1000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ranging);
        mContext = this;

        //....

        enableBluetooth();
        myctx = getApplicationContext();
        if (!createNewRegion()){
            finish();
        }
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(myctx);
        //BeaconManager.setRssiFilterImplClass(ArmaRssiFilter.class);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
                .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
        beaconManager.bind(this);
        //...

        //timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
        logToDisplay();
    }


    private boolean createNewRegion() {
        if ((strBeacon == null) || strBeacon.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            Identifier id1 = Identifier.parse(strBeacon.substring(0, 8) + "-" +
                    strBeacon.substring(8, 12) + "-" +
                    strBeacon.substring(12, 16) + "-" +
                    strBeacon.substring(16, 20) + "-" +
                    strBeacon.substring(20, 32));
            Identifier id2 = Identifier.parse(strBeacon.substring(32, 36));
            Identifier id3 = Identifier.parse(strBeacon.substring(36, 40));
            regionZebra = new Region(getRandomString(10), id1, id2, id3);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                showExitDialog(getString(R.string.exit_msg));
                return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private static final String ALLOWED_CHARACTERS = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";

    private static String getRandomString(final int sizeOfRandomString) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sizeOfRandomString);
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfRandomString; ++i)
            sb.append(ALLOWED_CHARACTERS.charAt(random.nextInt(ALLOWED_CHARACTERS.length())));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        restoreFindingDeviceState(0);
        if(null != beaconManager) {
            try {
                beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(regionZebra);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            beaconManager.unbind(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                showExitDialog(getString(R.string.exit_msg));
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
        if (beaconManager.isBound(this))
            beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);
        //restoreFindingDeviceState(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
        restoreFindingDeviceState(1);
        if (beaconManager.isBound(this))
            beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.startAnimation(buttonClick);
        String appendData = "";
        String uri = "";
        ServerConnect serverConnect = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.playsound:
                logMessage(TAG, "### Play sound button clicked" + uri);
                //Creates async task to communicate with server
                break;
            case R.id.found:
                //Show error to user
                //Creates async task to communicate with server
                break;
            case R.id.notfound:
               //Show error to user
               //Creates async task to communicate with server
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServerResponse(String response, int requestCode, String data) {
        //Process server response
    }

    public void refreshInfo() {


        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - findBeaconTime) > 40 * 1000) {
            //displayState = Constants.BEACON_FINDING;
            logToDisplay();
        }

       //Creates async task to communicate with server to pull the latest info
    }

    private String changeFormatofBeaconID(String id) {
        String retString = "";
        if (id != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4 - id.length(); i++) {
                retString = "0" + retString;
            }
        }
        return retString + id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

        beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                    for (Iterator<Beacon> iterator = beacons.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                        String id2 = "";
                        String id3 = "";
                        Beacon findBeacon = iterator.next();
                        if ((strBeacon == null) || (findBeacon == null)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        try {
                            //....
                            if (true == uuidReceived.startsWith(uuidToSearch)) {
                                displayBeacon = findBeacon;
                                displayState = Constants.BEACON_FOUND;
                                logToDisplay();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "### Exception when compare Beacon, UUID is null");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        beaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers();
        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            // If the phone enters a Beacon region
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
                try {
                    findBeaconTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // If the phone leaves a Beacon region
            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
                try {
                    displayState = Constants.BEACON_FINDING;
                    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - findBeaconTime) > 5 * 1000) {
                        logToDisplay();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {

            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(regionZebra);
       } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(regionZebra);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void showRanging(int mode) {

        webViewRanging = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewRanging);
        webViewRanging.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //for gif without background
        String gifName;
        if (mode == IMMEDIATE_RANGE)
            gifName = "immediate.gif";
        else if (mode == NEAR_RANGE)
            gifName = "near.gif";
        else if (mode == FAR_RANGE)
            gifName = "far.gif";
        else
            gifName = "none.gif";

        //Update the UI
    }


    private void logToDisplay() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                TextView txtShowDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRanging);
                switch (displayState) {
                    case Constants.BEACON_FOUND:
                        txtShowDistance.setText("");
                        if (displayBeacon.getDistance() <= 3) {
                            showRanging(IMMEDIATE_RANGE);
                        } else  if (3 < displayBeacon.getDistance() &&  displayBeacon.getDistance() <= 8) {
                            showRanging(NEAR_RANGE);
                        } else  if (displayBeacon.getDistance() > 8) {
                            showRanging(FAR_RANGE);
                        }
                        break;

                    case Constants.BEACON_FINDING:
                        if (bleStatus)
                            txtShowDistance.setText(R.string.out_of_bt_range);
                        else
                            txtShowDistance.setText(R.string.ble_off_msg);
                        txtShowDistance.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        showRanging(NOT_IN_RANGE);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static boolean enableBluetooth() {
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        boolean isEnabled = bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
        if (!isEnabled) {
            return bluetoothAdapter.enable();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void showFoundDialog(String msg) {
        //Show alert to the user clicks on found button when the device is found
       //Creates async task to communicate with the server
    }

    public void showNotFoundDialog(String msg) {
        //Show alert to the user clicks on not found button when the device is found
         //Creates async task to communicate with the server
    }

    private void restoreFindingDeviceState(int mode) {
        //Creates async task to communicate with server
    }

    public void showExitDialog(String msg) {
        //Show application exit dialog
         //Creates async task to communicate with the server
    }

    public void showStatusChangeDialog() {
       //Show server changed the status changed dialog
    }

    public void showSnackBarInfo(String info, int mode) {
        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(scrollLayout, info, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        if (mode == 1) {
            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
            sbView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            snackbar.setDuration(15*1000);
        }
        snackbar.setAction("DISMISS", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                snackbar.dismiss();
            }
        });

        snackbar.show();
    }

    private void handleSearchStatusError(int errorCode) {
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSearchStatusError called");
        switch (errorCode) {
            case Constants.WIFI_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                Log.e(TAG, "wifi not available");
                showErrorDialog(getString(R.string.details_wifi_not_connected), getString(R.string.wifi_error_desc));
                break;
            case Constants.ZDS_NOT_ENABLED:
                showErrorDialog(getString(R.string.zds_disabled), getString(R.string.zds_error_desc));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showErrorDialog(String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle(title).
                setMessage(message).setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        mDialog = null;
                    }
                });
        mDialog = builder.create();
        mDialog.show();
    }
}

}
```

Log Message Below:

```
01-30 10:43:21.582 30185-30492/com.company.myapp D/ServerConnect: ServerTask started:
01-30 10:43:21.583 30185-30492/com.company.myapp D/ServerConnect: ServerTask doInBackground ():/locationInfo/setDeviceCommand?<<deleted>>
    ServerTask doInBackground ():
01-30 10:43:21.587 30185-30492/com.company.myapp D/ServerConnect: url = <<deleted>>
01-30 10:43:23.436 30185-30578/com.company.myapp D/BeaconScanner: Find the Beaconid1: bd8a9fb8-613b-437f-f8a0-0dc8c7aedf06 id2: 0 id3: 71 type altbeacon
01-30 10:43:24.553 30185-30579/com.company.myapp D/BeaconScanner: Find the Beaconid1: bd8a9fb8-613b-437f-f8a0-0dc8c7aedf06 id2: 0 id3: 71 type altbeacon
01-30 10:43:25.674 30185-30580/com.company.myapp D/BeaconScanner: Find the Beaconid1: bd8a9fb8-613b-437f-f8a0-0dc8c7aedf06 id2: 0 id3: 71 type altbeacon
01-30 10:43:26.790 30185-30581/com.company.myapp D/BeaconScanner: Find the Beaconid1: bd8a9fb8-613b-437f-f8a0-0dc8c7aedf06 id2: 0 id3: 71 type altbeacon
01-30 10:43:27.902 30185-30583/com.company.myapp D/BeaconScanner: Find the Beaconid1: bd8a9fb8-613b-437f-f8a0-0dc8c7aedf06 id2: 0 id3: 71 type altbeacon
01-30 10:43:29.023 30185-30584/com.company.myapp D/BeaconScanner: Find the Beaconid1: bd8a9fb8-613b-437f-f8a0-0dc8c7aedf06 id2: 0 id3: 71 type altbeacon
01-30 10:43:30.135 30185-30585/com.company.myapp D/BeaconScanner: Find the Beaconid1: bd8a9fb8-613b-437f-f8a0-0dc8c7aedf06 id2: 0 id3: 71 type altbeacon
01-30 10:43:31.263 30185-30586/com.company.myapp D/BeaconScanner: Find the Beaconid1: bd8a9fb8-613b-437f-f8a0-0dc8c7aedf06 id2: 0 id3: 71 type altbeacon
01-30 10:43:31.817 30185-30492/com.company.myapp I/ServerConnect: Server Response code : 200
    Server Response : {<<deleted>>}
01-30 10:43:31.818 30185-30492/com.company.myapp D/ServerConnect: ServerTask started:
01-30 10:43:31.818 30185-30185/com.company.myapp D/ServerConnect: ServerTask: onPostExecute started
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason to be concerned about exhausting threads with the library is if you do long-running operations in the library's callback methods, `didEnterRegion` or more particularly `didRangeBeaconsInRegion`.  Since the code shown does not indicate any long running operations there, this should not be an issue.

The library uses an internal thread pool to parse beacon detections as they come in from the bluetooth stack.  This thread pool is initialized like this:

```
mExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1);
```

On a quad core processor, this would crate five threads to parse beacon packets.  Most of these are generally idle unless there is an extreme amount of Bluetooth LE traffic.  For the use case you describe, I would doubt that these threads are slowing down your processes.

You might find that the issue you describe is related to the AsyncTask you have set up and not related to beacon scanning.  One way to check this is to not start beacon ranging, and instead use some kind of a timer to simulate beacon events.  If the problem still exists, then that means it is not scanning-specific.

Here is a [sample app](https://github.com/davidgyoung/ningo-android) I wrote that does something similar, sending detections to a server.  It sends one request to a server for each beacon detected, and even with a large number of beacons in the vicinity, I have not seen such slowdowns.  You can see the AsyncTask implementation [here](https://github.com/davidgyoung/ningo-android/blob/master/NingoLibrary/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/ningo/RestRequest.java).

Comment: Thank you David. The problem was with creation of multiple AsyncTask to communicate with the Server. After replacing the AsycTask with Handler Thread or ThreadPoolExecutor, the problem got resolved.